# icons спрайт, что-то не так?

Tags: html, css, спрайт

Проблема в том что я не могу сделать спрайт.
В браузере стилей с этими классами ничего нет.

```
    <div class="icons">
        <a href="#" class="home"></a>
        <a href="#" class="mail"></a>
        <a href="#" class="folder"></a>
    </div>
```

css

```
        a {
        margin-left: 80px;
        background-image: url("../img/nav-sprite.png");
        background-position: 0 0;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 11px;
        height: 11px;

        .mail {background-position: -12px 0;}
        .folder {background-position: -24px 0;}

        &:first-child {
            margin-left: 60px;
        }
```

Вот картинка : [image: sprite]

Answer (score 2):

Что-то не так, скорее всего, в бездумной копипасте кода.

Если это CSS, для браузера он невалиден.

Если LESS, компилируется, если добавить закрывающую `}`  как

```
a {
    margin-left: 80px;
    background-image: url("../img/nav-sprite.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
}
a:first-child {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
a .mail {
    background-position: -12px 0;
}
a .folder {
    background-position: -24px 0;
}
```

Как результат:

> В браузере стилей с этими классами ничего нет

Comment: Это sass или scss в скобках все вроде бы правильно но спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо но проблема была в стилях надо было вложить все стили в родителя

```
    .icons {
        float: left;
        .mail {
            background-position: -12px 0;
        }
        .folder {
            background-position: -24px 0;
        }

        a {
            margin-left: 80px;
            background-image: url("../img/nav-sprite.png");
            background-position: 0 0;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 11px;
            height: 11px;

            &:first-child {margin-left: 60px;}
        }
    }
```